# Quicksight - How to use log() in a calculated field?

Tags: amazon-web-services, looker-studio, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to move my BI dashboards from Google Data Studio to Quicksight.

In Data Studio, I use a log() function in a calculated fields. My formula is "`20 * LOG(SUM(event_count))`".

How could I do that same calculation on the go with QuickSight (calculated field) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the moment, logarithms are not supported in QuickSight's calculated functions.

The documentation has a list of [supported functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/functions.html) that I would recommend checking out, although, some of them only appear to be available in data preparation.

I would recommend opening a feature request via the [AWS console's support section.](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#)

**Update (1/6/2020)**

The QuickSight team has recently released `log`: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/amazon-quicksight-launches-new-analytical-functions-athena-workgroup-and-presto-vpc-connector-support/.